# How would I make a condition that requires an odd number in a certain range?

Tags: python

Here is a pretty simple example of what I mean:

```
def work():
    x = input("Give me a number : ")
    if x in range(30000):
        print "hello"
```

So as long as I put in a number in that range it will print hello, but what if I want it to only accept an odd number in that range? I tried defining a separate function that's range is only odd numbers like this:

```
def work():
    a = input("Give me a number : ")
    if a in range(30000):
       X = range(30001)
       y = (2*X)-1
       if a in range(y):
           print "hello"
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: We all knew what you meant by "but that doesn't work", but in the future you should be more specific.  Doesn't work can mean a lot of different things.

Comment: Would you please show us the output you're getting and the one you're expecting?

Comment: Is this python2 or python3?  I get the feeling you are using python2 because you are using the result of `input` as an `int` without converting it with the `int` function.

Answer (score 6):

```
if 0 <= x < 30000 and x % 2 == 1:
    print "hello"
```

Comment: This is *actually* what the OP wants.  It is WAY more efficient.

Comment: @SethMMorton: Right... Tks!: )

Comment: The OP didn't state this explicitly, but based on the fact they were checking membership of `range` I'm guessing they only want integers.  There are many ways to check that a number is an integer, but an easy way is `if int(x) == x:`.  I'm just pointing this out in case this was a conscious decision of the OP to use `range` for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: Python 2.x didn't do the optimisation - so this only applies to Python 3.x's `range`**

You can take advantage that `xrange` (or `range` in 3.x - needn't generate the list and can do membership testing...) by providing it with a step parameter as well as the start and end stops...

So, you could use to check for odd numbers up until 30000:

```
if number in xrange(1, 30000, 2):
    pass
```

eg:

```
>>> for number in (1, 2, 3, 999999):
    print number in xrange(1, 30000, 2)

True
False
True
False
```

Comment: For a large list like this, would it be more efficient to do `numbers = set(xrange(1, 30000, 2)); if number in numbers:`?  It's just a curiosity.

Comment: @SethMMorton nope - `xrange` has a custom membership test that can computer membership mathematically - not by actually requiring anything to be materialised and then hashed as per a `set`

Comment: Good to know... that's a good tip.  I'm assuming that this is true of `range` in python3 as well?  Also, can you point me to the documentation for that feature of `xrange`?

Comment: @SethMMorton umm... Struggling to find a reference... I'm sure I've seen it - or I might be confusing it with a proposal or something else... one sec

Answer (score 0):

An odd number doesn't divide by 2, so you verify this using the [modulo operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

```
x % 2
```

In Python a number not equal to 0 is considered `True`, so this will do the work:

```
def work():
    x = input("Give me a number : ")
    if x in range(30000) and x % 2:
        print "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to list the numbers, here is a general way to do this (but you should just use the `range()` function):

```
def every(increment, range, offset=0):
    current = offset
    yield current
    while(1):
        current += increment
        if current < range:
           yield current
        else:
           break
```

So for odds to 30,000 it would be :

```
for i in every(2, 30000, 1):
    ...
```

Comment: You're re-inventing `range` though: This is equivalent to: `range(1, 30000, 2)`

Comment: Isn't this reinventing the wheel?  Take a look at the answer by @JonClements

Comment: @JonClements I'm new to python, I'll check out what you posted.

Comment: @JonClements I wasn't aware of the step parameter in the range function, also this doesn't answer the question - for some reason I thought he wanted to list them. Thanks for pointing this out.